# This tag is so ambiguous that we have no [choice] but to burninate it

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The [choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/choice) tag has 456 questions and no tag usage guidance.

It's used for everything from dropdown menus in various languages to XSD to [NumPy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy).

That being said:

- This tag is highly ambiguous
- It does *not* mean the same thing in all common contexts
- It does not add anything valuable to the questions

Given this tag's ambiguity, I think we have no [choice] but to burninate it.

Comment: title suggestion: [choice] [x]

Comment: My `choice` here is  `[✓] Burnination [ ] Not burnination`